# jQuery Syntax for conditional logic with radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

My form is supposed to show an image based on the radio buttons selected in two different fields (form & color).

I have managed to create objects with links as values of each property.
Now how do I tell jQuery to change the source of #image if for example I choose gold + round?

Here is a fiddle with dummy pics: https://jsfiddle.net/fbzf10x6/10/

```
<body>
  <form action="">
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver"> silver
<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="gold"> gold
<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="platin"> platin
<br> <br>

<input type="radio" name="form" value="round"> round
<br>
<input type="radio" name="form" value="oval"> oval
<br>

</form>

<div><img id="image" src="#"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think your object in the fiddle doesn't serve what you need in base of your explanation here.

The object should contain combinations like:
`images = {silverround: "link1", silveroval: "link2",.... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onClick** method and a **JavaScript function** to reload the **src attribute value** of your image element.

Below a quick example:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function reloadImgSrc(value) {
            document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = '<img src="/img/'+value+'.jpg"  />';
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
          <form action="">
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver" onclick="reloadImgSrc('silver')"> silver
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="gold" onclick="reloadImgSrc('gold')"> gold
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="platin" onclick="reloadImgSrc('platin')"> platin

        </form>

        <div id="image"></div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your code to retain the pair of values that is selected, and use both values to find the image URL in your object:

```
var current = {
  color: 'silver', form: 'oval'
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=color],input[name=form]").change(function() {
    current[this.name] = this.value;
    $('#image').stop().fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', images[current.form][current.color]);
    }).fadeIn(200);
  });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbzf10x6/20/)

Comment: Thank you!! That works incredibly well!
If I were to add a third option such as "size" - could I follow the same logic and just add it in the same manner as you did? I reckon it gets quite complicated... I would add it on the same "level" as color right?

Comment: You would have to add a level of object nesting in your `images` object. Another way to do it, is to follow a strict naming convention in your image file names. Like 'silver-oval-big.png', making sure the parts in that name correspond exactly to the values of your radio buttons. Then you can generate the image file name without the need of the *images* object.

Answer (score 0):

The point of interest is:

```
$(this).attr('src', paths[images]);
```

The paths is undefined.

If no input with name form is selected inside the change handler I prefer to set the first and so after I can address the right image: images[formChecked][colorChecked].

My snippet:

```js
var images = {
  oval: {
    silver: "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=38201084",
    gold: "http://images.betteridge.com/images/products/standard/BCA-16-17-14kt-yellow-gold-oval-signet-ring.jpg",
    platin: "http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/g/09UAAOSwBPNXR3UH/s-l225.jpg"
  },

  round: {
    silver: "http://www.silverringjewelry.com/silver-rings/fine-silver-rings.jpg",
    gold: "https://img0.etsystatic.com/031/1/6658158/il_340x270.596198132_jls1.jpg",
    platin: "http://images.costco-static.com/image/media/350-703887-847__1.jpg"
  }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name="color"]').first().prop('checked', true);
  $('input[name="form"]').last().prop('checked', true);

  
  $('input[name="color"], input[name="form"]').change(function (e) {
    var colorChecked;
    var formChecked;
    if (this.name == "color") {
      colorChecked = this.value;
      formChecked = $('input[name="form"]:checked').val()
    } else {
      colorChecked = $('input[name="color"]:checked').val();
      formChecked = this.value;
    }

    $('#image').stop().fadeOut(200, function () {
      $(this).attr('src', images[formChecked][colorChecked]);
    }).fadeIn(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver"> silver
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="gold"> gold
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="platin"> platin
    <br> <br>

    <input type="radio" name="form" value="round"> round
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="oval"> oval
    <br>

</form>

<div><img id="image" src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=38201084"></div>
```

Comment: Thats great thank you! But somehow nothing happens when checking either round or oval. Only color changes the images.